# Symfony2 Create Models

Tags: symfony

Reading Symfony documentation I did not see that talking about **Models**.

The first thought I thought: *I do not want to mix business logic*

I dont want **DQL** in my controller actions. What about MVC than.

My idea is next:

- Create new directory in bundle with name **Models**
- Set __ namespace __ for that model and ( **use** ) attach the necessary Doctrine class
- In my Model class i put DQL logic connected with Entity

Next in controller use current Model.

Just simple controller action whitout mixing DQL in controller

```
  use Company\Bundle\Models\MyModel;

 public function getRecentMembersAction($max = 3)
    {
        $model = new Model() // get model
        $list = $model->getRecentMembers($max); // DQL

        // Render
        return $this->render('CompanyBundle:Controller.index.html.twig', array('list'=>$list);
    }
```

My question is whether this is a good idea and good practice?

**SLOVED:** http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#entity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your DQL in [repositories](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes). And keep your domain logic in the [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).

**Controller Layer → Service Layer → Repository Layer**

This way you can have several controller types — HTML, REST, command line — all using the same domain logic encapsulated in the Service Layer.

And the Repository Layer encapsulates all the persisting functionality so that you can swap an ORM Repository Layer with an ODM Repository Layer or some other type of Repository Layer — like Web service calls, persisting to text files, etc.

Comment: I was just about to answer the same :) +1

Comment: Just a second. my entity `Product` must have one more class inside `Entity` directory `ProductRepository` right. And with annotation in `Product Entity` i set what `repositoryClass` need to use. And my `ProductRespository` contain `DQL`.

Comment: I found this and understand: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#entity